# Postgresql 9.4.6 odd sorting behavior on OSX vs Linux

Tags: linux, macos, postgresql, sorting

When I run this on linux and Mac OSX with Postgres 9.4.6 I get different ordering. Is this a bug in Postgres?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SORTER ( name VARCHAR );
INSERT INTO SORTER (name) VALUES ('A B'); 
INSERT INTO SORTER (name) VALUES ('AB'); 
INSERT INTO SORTER (name) VALUES ('A C'); 
INSERT INTO SORTER (name) VALUES ('AC'); 
SELECT * FROM SORTER ORDER BY name; 
SELECT * FROM SORTER ORDER BY name DESC;
```

OSX:

```
name
------
 A B
 A C
 AB
 AC
(4 rows)

 name
------
 AC
 AB
 A C
 A B
(4 rows)
```

Linux:

```
name 
------
AB
A B
AC
A C
(4 rows)

name 
------
A C
AC
A B
AB
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Looks like this has to do with the LOCALE in which you are running, so it's a glibc issue not postgresql... https://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/422360-sorting-spaces-postgresql-en_us-locale

Comment: Yep appears to be using `en_US` locale for Linux and `C` for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the LC_CTYPE on the schema is UTF-8. For some reason on mac it is set to C.

To fix it you can add a `collate 'C'` option to the Linux side.

Comment: This saved us a LOT of time. Thank you! Here's another great article that explains the importance of collation as it pertains to sorting things and locales: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94887/what-is-the-impact-of-lc-ctype-on-a-postgresql-database